# Windows 10 Falls Back to IGMPv2

Tags: windows, multicast, igmp

I have a setup where I have a Linux server running an 802.11n WPA2 encrypted Wi-Fi network. There are two devices connected to this network. One is a device which generates reports and the other is a Windows 10 laptop which downloads these reports. In order for the Windows 10 laptop to find the device it uses IGMP multicast to send out a request for the device and the device, if present responds.

Upon booting up the laptop and connecting to the network this sequence of events works great. I can run wireshark and see the laptop use IGMPv3 to listen on the required addresses and the request and response all takes place as expected.

However, I run into trouble if I take the laptop and wander out of range of the Wi-Fi. Once I come back I reconnect to the Wi-Fi network and once again attempt to find my device. This time through wireshark I see Windows register to listen for multicast using ICMPv2 packets. In this case when I search for the device I see the request go out but do not see the response. Doing a packet capture on the router though I can see that the device is indeed responding in both cases.

Can anyone shed some light on what might be happening in this second case?

Comment: Can't say for sure but it appears to be a problem in your Linux access point. It receives the MC and doesn't pass it on after it was unsubscribed for a while. Have you checked whether there is any difference in subscription after reboot and after wandering off?